# Vector to Raster

Tags: raster, vector, classification, land-cover, fragstats

I traced land use as forest (purple) and non-forest (Teal) in my study area of 117sq.km. from google earth. I have attached a copy of the landcover file which I have created. I need to convert this into a raster with two classes (forest and non-forest).

-> I added the kml files from Google Earth as layers in QGIS and then converted them to shapefile files 
-> merged the non-forest and forest shapefiles and 
-> then categorised them with the option provided under symbology.
Now, I want to rasterise the merged shapefile and do not know how to. I have tried rasterizing the shapefile using the rasterize options in the processing toolbar (GDAL and SAGA). There is no output if I use GDAL and there is a raster file which I obtain with SAGA but there is no difference in coloration, which I find confusing to interpret.

My ultimate goal is to analyse the land-cover in fragstats.

[image]

Comment: I suggest that you have fallen into one of the most common pitfalls of this process, that your vector is geographic coordinates (KML/KMZ are **always** WGS84/Geographic) so your cell size is enormous and you're only getting a single cell over the entire layer at best. Use 'save as' from the table of contents and pick a suitable projected coordinate system for your output (WGS84/UTM should work over the size of your data extent). When your data is in metres your cell size won't be as huge and you should get a result that you can use.

Comment: @MichaelStimson: Yes! Yes! It worked :D. I could generate my raster!